# Finding Unique Data

Tags: r

this is something I've asked previously and found a solution to; however, the framing of the question has changed a bit and I'm having trouble trying to figure out a new solution.

The problem: I have three different land-use categories (forest, urban, and agriculture), each with 15 sites and each site has data for ~24,145 molecular formulae. I'm trying to figure out which of the 24,145 molecular formulae is unique to each land-use (occurs in one but does not occur in the other two) and is present in at least 3 of the sites.

Below is an example of the data I'm working with. In this example, and eventually in the final product, I would want something that shows that Forest has Formula 2 as being unique to that land-use, Agriculture has Formula 1 as being unique to that land-use, and Urban has Formula 5 as being unique to that land-use. Formulas 3 and 4 are not unique to any land-uses in this example as they both appear in multiple sites in one land-use category but they also appear in one sample for another land-use category. Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide!

```
Forest dataframe (Forestdf)
       Formula 1.      Formula 2.     Formula 3.    Formula 4.     Formula 5.
Site 1         0             0.11            0.4           0.2             0
Site 2         0             0.00            0.0           0.3             0
Site 3         0             0.22            0.0           0.0             0
Site 4         0             0.08            0.0           0.2             0
Site 5         0             0.13            0.0           0.2             0

Agriculture dataframe (Agdf)
       Formula 1.      Formula 2.     Formula 3.    Formula 4.     Formula 5.
Site 1        0.4               0              0           0.0             0
Site 2        0.4               0              0           0.0             0
Site 3        0.0               0              0           0.0             0
Site 4        0.0               0              0           0.2             0
Site 5        0.3               0              0           0.0             0

Urban dataframe (Urbandf)
       Formula 1.      Formula 2.     Formula 3.    Formula 4.     Formula 5.
Site 1         0                0            0.4             0            0.11
Site 2         0                0            0.2             0            0.13
Site 3         0                0            0.3             0            0.00
Site 4         0                0            0.3             0            0.12
Site 5         0                0            0.4             0            0.21

Using dput for the first 5 rows and first 5 columns
Forestdf:
structure(list(C10H10O3N1S0.C13_0 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O4N1S0.C13_0 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O5N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.130234152, 0.145453043, 
0.138632224, 0.137966545, 0.156719097), C10H10O5N1S1.C13_0 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O6N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.25860961, 0.178788706, 
0.24269712, 0.342992525, 0.275922979)), row.names = c("Site1", 
"Site2", "Site3", "Site4", 
"Site5"), class = "data.frame")

Agdf:
structure(list(C10H10O3N1S0.C13_0 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O4N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.090063118, 
0.073495534, 0.086842224, 0, 0.102037015), C10H10O5N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.2019056, 
0.252455406, 0.261273537, 0.231026084, 0.228051503), C10H10O5N1S1.C13_0 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O6N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.270212549, 0.410897288, 
0.389682591, 0.406200693, 0.371324053)), row.names = c("Site1", 
"Site2", "Site3", "Site4", "Site5"
), class = "data.frame")

Urbandf
structure(list(C10H10O3N1S0.C13_0 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C10H10O4N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.125577432, 
0, 0.133996693, 0.130540536, 0.200570837), C10H10O5N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.323671408, 
0.216539327, 0.353390807, 0.402114649, 0.457133067), C10H10O5N1S1.C13_0 = c(0, 
0, 0.128134269, 0, 0.135903898), C10H10O6N1S0.C13_0 = c(0.779110684, 
0.408483268, 0.58690704, 0.665475412, 0.646630398)), row.names = c("Site1", 
"Site2", "Site3", "Site4", "Site5"
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example using dput(), dump() or structure()?

Comment: @HaciDuru I've added examples using dput of the first 5 rows and first 5 columns of each land use data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
Forest = apply(Forestdf[-1], 2, function(x) {length(x[which(x != 0)])})
Ag = apply(Agdf[-1], 2, function(x) {length(x[which(x != 0)])})
Urban = apply(Urbandf[-1], 2, function(x) {length(x[which(x != 0)])})
formulae = data.frame(Forest, Ag, Urban)

landuses = names(formulae)
formulae$uniqueto = ''
formulae$uniqueto = apply(formulae, 1, function(x) {
                        if (length(x[which(x != 0)]) == 1){
                            if (max(x) > 2) {
                                landuses[which(x > 2)]
                            } else {
                                ''
                            }
                        } else {
                            ''
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Thanks @HaciDuru, that worked! I'm still relatively new to using R so could you possibly point out where in the code it limits the land-use assignment to formulae present in at least 3 sites? I may eventually change it so that the formulae has to be present in all 15 sites for one of the land-use categories instead of just 3 sites.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that restriction. I edited the solution, please see it. I check for that condition here: if (max(x) > 2) {

Comment: I'm getting the following error and I'm not quite sure how to fix it: Error in which(x != 0) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'